# Shared Multisite Settings

Tags: configuration

Using a Drupal Multisite system, is it possible to have a base set of configuration settings shared across multiple sites?

That is, each site in Drupal has a `settings.php` file

```
default/settings.php
site1/settings.php
site2/settings.php
anothersite/settings.php
```

Is there a master `settings.php` where I could set a configuration value once and have it apply to **all** my sites?

Or is this normally handled at the deployment level?

Comment: Anything wrong with adding `require '/path/to/master.php';` to each of the settings.php files?

Comment: @Clive Ask the developers who take over this project and don't know about the `master.php` file.  (but that's probably what I'll end up doing if there's no native Drupal solution)

Comment: I'd imagine that info would be on the handover docs but I get what you're saying. Hard to think of a native Drupal solution, Because of the way settings.php is included I think you're out of luck (short of server wizardry, but that has the same problem you've already mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

so for what it's worth using the `default/settings.php` as the master and then having each of the sites do a PHP include (as @[Alan](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/312/alan-storm) mentions) does work well!  (*I know this is an old question but I am working through multisite issues with Drupal 8 (8.6.13) and have come across this very thing...*)

a couple of caveats:

1) I am managing the multisite installation and config manually so am creating *my own* `settings.php` files, not using `drush site-install` which will auto-generate the `settings.php`

2) you must do the include at the top of the site's `settings.php` and ensure that you are overriding only what you need to. (...or the inverse, that you are okay using the config in the default settings file)

I have this at the top of the `settings.php` for each site:

```
$default_path = "sites/default";
include $app_root . '/' . $default_path . '/settings.php';
```

and then override the database settings - setting the prefix etc:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'this_is_the_database',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'prefix' => array(
    'default'         => 'site1_prefix_',
  ... etc
```

and the site name:

```
$config['system.site']['name'] = 'Site 1 Name will override default site name';
```

of course YMMV

tl;dr - yes you can, but be aware of the order in which your PHP will execute and apply the settings

Answer (score 1):

The general consensus seems to be

> No, you can't do that

without resorting to a raw PHP include.